# Converting Stored Procedure to Inline Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, inline-functions

I need to perform update but with stored procedure I can't use It.So I m no choice then converting to function.
This is my Stored procedure.

```
alter Proc spIsUnique
@columnname nvarchar(max),
@tablename nvarchar(max)
As
Begin
EXEC ('select IIf (count(*)>1,''False'',''True'') as [IsUnique-check] 
        from '+@tablename+' 
        group by '+@columnname)
End
```

I try to convert it to inline function

```
create Function fn_IsUnique(
@columnname nvarchar(max),
@tablename nvarchar(max)
) returns table
As
return
select IIf (count(*)>1,'False','True') as [IsUnique-check] 
        from @tablename
        group by @columnname
```

It throws me this error

```
Must declare the table variable "@tablename
```

Help me convert scored procedure to inline function.
Edited:-
If it is not possible to convert into inline function.
Any alternative way How can I use result of this stored procedure into update statement.

Comment: Unfortunately you will not be able to do what you are trying to do here, because when using object names as variables (Tables, views etc) you have to use dynamic sql and use `exec` or `sp_executesql` , SQL Server functions has this limitation , you CAN NOT CALL A Stored Procedure from inside a function.

Comment: Then any alternative.How to update

Comment: No alternative to what you are trying to do, it cannot be done, but passing a table type parameter to your stored procedure and returning a table from it may get you somewhere close to where you wanna be.

Comment: What you ask doesn't make much sense if you consider how a query runs. The query is the script that the server compiles into an execution plan *based on the data's statistics and indexes*. Different tables result in different execution plans. The server caches that plan so that it doesn't have to recompile the query each time.

Comment: BTW if you want to create a profile of a table's data, including unique columns, value distribution, null frequencies etc you can use the Data Profile Task in SSIS.

Comment: The query is wrong too. It *doesn't* check for uniquness. You'd still get a count of 1 if there was only one row in a table.

Comment: What UPDATE statement? You have a query that doesn't return what you think it does and ask about an UPDATE that you haven't posted

Comment: please see 1st line.I have said it. and According to M.Ali i can't use dynamic sql into inline variable. So suggest me 
How can I use stored procedure in update statement.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FnRetCnt
(
    @tablename nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Ret BIT

    DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
       Cnt INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @t
    SELECT
       SUM(st.row_count)
       FROM
         sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
       WHERE
          object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @t WHERE Cnt>0)
       SET @Ret = 0
    ELSE
       SET @Ret = 1

    RETURN @Ret

END
go

SELECT
    dbo.FnRetCnt('AddressType')
```

Comment: Why does this answer the question? The OP is asking for columns with unique values.